# Integer overflow and Multiplication of integers in c++

Tags: c++, floating-point, integer, multiplication, integer-overflow

```
    int y ;
    y = 7000000000*1.0;
```

This does not give an error in cpp

Though

```
    int y ;
    y = 7000000000;
```

This leads to integer overflow

Can anyone please explain these two scenarios.

Comment: The result of `7000000000*1.0` is a `double`. `7000000000` doesn't fit in an `int`.

Comment: I have seen a few 64 bit `int`s that can hold 7000000000, but they are uncommon.

Comment: If we stick to the C++ Standard, and we haven't been given a target compiler or platform so the Standard is all we have to go on, these scenarios have [undefined behaviour](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/behavior) and cannot be explained. Note: g++ 8.3 with `-pedantic -Wall -Wextra -Wconversion` emits warnings for both.

Comment: @user4581301: The integer conversion is implementation-defined, not undefined (C++ 2017 draft n4659 7.8 3).

Comment: What do you mean by "in cpp"? There is a program called [cpp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_preprocessor), but that just pre-processes code and would not give an error for what you presented. So maybe you mean "C++"? If so, it's not the language giving you the error but your compiler. So you might need to mention which compiler you are using, and which compiler options produce an error for the latter but not the former.

Comment: My compiler generates a warning for the first code, and at runtime it outputs `runtime error: 7e+09 is outside the range of representable values of type 'int'`, and sets y to 0.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your C++ implementation, both `y = 7000000000*1.0` and `y = 7000000000` result overflowing what is representable in an `int` during conversion. For conversion from a floating-point type to an integer type, the behavior in the event of such overflow is not defined by the C++ standard. For conversion from one integer type to another, it is implementation-defined.

However, your compiler diagnoses the latter during compilation and fails to diagnose the former. This does not mean the former is okay (it is not), simply that the compiler does not report the problem (and is not required to by the C++ standard).

Comment: [conv.fpint] A prvalue of a floating-point type can be converted to a prvalue of an integer type.
The conversion truncates; that is, the fractional part is discarded.
**The behavior is undefined** if the truncated value cannot be represented in the destination type. -- Just to be clear :)

Comment: @eerorika: I am not sure what point you are clarifying. That overflow occurs only if the truncated value does not fit, rather than some property of the source value before truncation? That the specification comes from a particular part of the standard? Something else?

Comment: I'm clarifying the "behavior ... is not defined by the C++ standard" part of the answer. That's a bit vague and doesn't necessarily convey the same meaning as undefined behaviour.

Comment: @eerorika: It is not vague, and I deliberately use that wording because it is better. People use “undefined” with the C and C++ standards as if it were a thing, notably a thing that you must do because the behavior is not defined. But that is a false understanding of what “undefined” means in the standard. It literally means what I have written: It is not defined by the standard. It is not a thing, it is a lack of a thing. It is like a city that says “when you leave city limits, we do not guarantee you electricity, water, or police.” But then you are somewhere else, and you may find other…

Comment: … other suppliers for your needs. Unfortunately, too many people treat “undefined” in the C and C++ standards as if they meant “the city prohibits this action; if you do it, you violate a law.” That is not the case. The standards intend for implementations to provide extensions, and extensions are necessarily for the vast majority of commercially useful programs. Only purely text interactions and purely abstract computations can be done in strictly conforming C or C++. Linking to any other library requires using “undefined” behavior, including GUI interactions, network connections, and more.

Comment: Writing that something is “not defined by the standard” makes it more apparent that it is **open** to be defined by something else. Writing that something is “undefined” is falsely taken by some as **closed** and off limits, as if it must remain undefined. It is an unfortunate choice of terminology in the standards, and I eschew it.